# Printing html page with fixed footer with Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, positioning

Good afternoon people. I sux with css son I wish someone can give me a hand with this. I'm trying to print some kind of html text taken from a html page with a header and a footer. This footer has to stays on the bottom of the page, if is there a second page it should appear on the bottom on that page. Anyway, I got [this](http://jsfiddle.net/F3kSQ/1/) fiddle to show. The html looks great but when I print the page with a pdf printer, the text overlaps the footer, but only in Firefox, if a run the fiddle on Chrome, it prints the footer below the last paragraph on the second page.

Any idea how to implement this idea?

Answer (score 0):

In your final div, remove the `position:absolute`, `left` and `top` css styles. You are positioning the footer overtop of everything. The value for `top` would have to be manually adjusted for each browser and you probably want to stay away from that.

Here is an updated fiddle with those css styles removed from your footer div: http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/F3kSQ/2/

Comment: Yes it works but it keeps appearing on the middle of the second page. Is there a trick to keep the footer on the bottom of the second page? And if the content of the first page doesnt fill the entire page, ithe footer appears on the middle of the page.Thanks!